# Anyone able to work with shadow copy from a .Net app running on Vista?

Tags: windows, backup, shadow-copy

The background information, libraries and sample code on the [Joe Lynds](http://www.jlion.com/docs/vshadow.aspx) site is really helpful and works fine with XP. There are also other code samples around to help with XP shadow copy.

Advice on using shadow copying from a .NET app running on Vista / Win7 is thinner on the ground. Joe Lynds site offers a wrapper which claims to work across XP, Vista, 32bit & 64bit versions, but we couldn't get it to run on Vista.

Has anyone else been able to crack this?

We are using .Net 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used the [AlphaVSS](http://alphavss.codeplex.com/) library with some success.